# The instance member ‘widget’ can’t be accessed in an initializer. Try replacing the reference to the instance member with a different expression

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I am passing the data to another screen but while retrieving it i am getting error,

Here is the code for how i am passing the data

```
TextButton(
   onPressed: ()  async {
 
     final QuerySnapshot result =
     await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection(
         'ActiveUsers').get();
     final List<DocumentSnapshot> documents = result
         .docs;
     var data = (documents..shuffle());
         await Navigator.of(context)
            .push(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => ChatScreen(receiverId: data.first.id)));
 
 
          },
```

Here is the code for retrieving.

```
class ChatScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  final String receiverId;
   const ChatScreen({Key key, @required this.receiverId}) : super(key: key,);
 
   @override
   State<ChatScreen> createState() => _ChatScreenState();
 }
 
 class _ChatScreenState extends State<ChatScreen> {
   bool isDarkTheme = false;
  String id = widget.receiverId;
```

Here is the structure of my database
[image: database]

i tried assigning through `initstate` as i am able to use `widget.receiverId` inside `initstate` but if i am assigning it again i am getting error.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `initState` or lazy initialization adding `late` like

```dart
late String id = widget.receiverId;
```